# Confusing formatting near share links

Tags: bug, status-completed

When a question has been marked as a favorite, a number appears below the star icon.  This is great, but with the facebook/twitter links below the number is a bit confusing.

I'm not initially sure whether that means that 1 person has shared the question on facebook, or whether one has marked it as a favorite.

[image: Confusing formatting around favorites and share links]

I'd like if this was a clearer distinction. That might be as simple as leaving more space between the items, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I can put more spacing between the share icons and the favorite count, but probably not by too much. The reason is that column of buttons drives the height of the question area too. So if the question is short, the right side will end up having a lot of white space.

Comment: Makes sense... could the count be a little closer to the fav. icon? I think part of the problem is that there is less space below the count than above.

Comment: yes. i'll put in a fix for it.